# Why does a polynomial's degree reduce when the leading coefficient approaches $0$ (but not equal to $0$)?

Tags: limits, polynomials

Here is the definition of a polynomial taken from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polynomial.html)

> A polynomial is a mathematical expression involving a sum of powers in one or more variables multiplied by coefficients. A polynomial in one variable (i.e., a univariate polynomial) with constant coefficients is given by
>   $$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_ix^i$$

A polynomial is said to be an $nth$ degree polynomial if the highest power of the variable is $n$ and the leading coefficient is **not equal** to $0$.

Now, take the following case: 
$$f(x) = \lim_{a_n \to 0} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_ix^i = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_ix^i$$

Now, this shows that the degree of the polynomial $$\lim_{a_n \to 0} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_ix^i$$

is $n - 1$. Now, here is another thing from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function)

> To say that 
>   $$\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = L,$$
>   means that $f(x)$ can be made as close as desired to $L$ by making $x$ close enough, but **not equal**, to $p$.

It means in the expression 
$$\lim_{a_n \to 0} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_ix^i$$

the value of $a_n$ is infinitesimally close to $0$ but $a_n \ne 0$. This means that the degree of the polynomial is $n$.

So, my question **is that is it just because $a_n$ is extremely close to zero that we consider it to be equal to zero? If so, then is the degree of the expression $n - 1$?**

Comment: A concrete example is useful. Suppose $y(x)=\epsilon x-1$: If $\epsilon$ is finite then there's a single root at $x=1/\epsilon$, but this root flies away to $\infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ and no other roots remain. This is an example of a _singular_ perturbation, since the case of $\epsilon$ small but finite is not properly approximated by taking $\epsilon=0$. By contrast, when $y(x)=x-\epsilon$ then the root at $x=\epsilon$ moves to zero as $\epsilon\to 0$ and is well-behaved, corresponding to a regular perturbation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observations show that the "degree function" (which associates the degree of $p$ to each polynomial $p$) is *discontinuous* on the space of polynomials, in the precise sense that if
$$
p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k} x^{k},\quad a_{n} \neq 0,
$$
then
$$
\lim_{a_{n} \to 0} (\deg p) = n > \deg(\lim_{a_{n} \to 0} p).
$$

Comment: Sorry but I still didn't understand the inequality of your last expression.

Comment: If $a_{n} \neq 0$, you have $\deg p = n$. Consequently, $\lim\limits_{a_{n} \to 0} (\deg p) = \lim\limits_{a_{n} \to 0} n = n$.

Comment: But what about the inequality? I don't think that taking degree of $p$ as $a_n \to 0$ would be less than $n$.

Comment: My apology; I mis-read your comment. If $p$ has the stated form (contains no terms of degree greater than $n$) and $a_{n} = 0$ (namely, after you've taken the limit of $p$ as $a_{n} \to 0$), then $n > \deg p$.

Comment: But limit means that the variable becomes infinitesimally close to the limit point but **not equal to it**. So wouldn't it mean that $n = deg (p)$? Or is it just that the minute difference is neglected?

Comment: Neither; it's completely analogous to saying $\lim\limits_{a_{n} \to 0} a_{n} = 0$. It's true that the _definition of a limit_ $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ explicitly excludes considering $x = a$, but that doesn't prevent the _value of the limit_ from being $f(a)$.

Comment: Considering what you said, shouldn't $$\lim_{a_n \to 0} deg(p) = n - 1$$ because as you stated, $a_n$ can be equal to zero. So, $deg(p)$ would be equal to n - 1.

Comment: The degree could be strictly smaller than $n - 1$: think of $p(x) = a_{n} x^{n} + x$, say, for which the degree drops from $n$ to $1$.

Comment: Agreed. But I still didn't understand the inequality. Why is the RHS less than the LHS? I think both should be equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45509/discussion-between-andrew-d-hwang-and-unknowncoder).